# How to debug php script that exits with 137 error?

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I have long running worker that iterates over 5M records using batch processing. I use standard Laravel's function chunkById for this.

As long as i can see, i have not reached 200M of memory usage, which i can see in output of `docker stats`:

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                                                      CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
fd05760e5d96        case-place-partners_case-place-partners_app_1             21.71%              140.5MiB / 7.666GiB   1.79%               919MB / 103MB       113MB / 21.4MB      19
```

Additionally, i have `memory_get_usage()` and `memory_get_usage(true)` everywhere and i dont see numbers higher than `52428800`.

Output of `journalctl -k | grep -i -e memory -e oom`:

```
Aug 19 09:28:41 mirokko-i3 kernel: Memory: 8023772K/8259584K available (12291K kernel code, 1319K rwdata, 3900K rodata, 1612K init, 3616K bss, 235812K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
Aug 19 09:28:41 mirokko-i3 kernel: Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 32K
Aug 19 09:28:41 mirokko-i3 kernel: x86/mm: Memory block size: 128MB
Aug 19 09:28:41 mirokko-i3 kernel: Freeing initrd memory: 9024K
Aug 19 09:28:41 mirokko-i3 kernel: check: Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
Aug 19 09:28:41 mirokko-i3 kernel: Freeing unused decrypted memory: 2040K
Aug 19 09:28:41 mirokko-i3 kernel: Freeing unused kernel image memory: 1612K
Aug 19 09:28:41 mirokko-i3 kernel: Freeing unused kernel image memory: 2012K
Aug 19 09:28:41 mirokko-i3 kernel: Freeing unused kernel image memory: 196K
Aug 19 09:28:57 mirokko-i3 kernel: [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 4019344 KiB
Aug 19 09:28:57 mirokko-i3 kernel: [TTM] Zone   dma32: Available graphics memory: 2097152 KiB
```

Output of `docker inspect container_id` located [here](https://pastebin.com/wWYHfHW9)

Comment: does it exit with that code if you run the script with 100 records instead of 5M?

Comment: it exits after 2-3 minutes

Comment: try having a look at the journal: `journalctl -k | grep -i -e memory -e oom` or `docker inspect container_id`

Comment: @Evhz updated my answer. Nothing really usefull there, on my opinion. No errors, everything works fine (according to logs, not results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Laravel has job timeout. Just run worker with `--timeout="0"` to disable this feature or set your own value.